# How to change order of indexes based on my opinion not based on some key in Pandas Data Frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have Data Frame in pandas like below:

```
IDX    col1
------|-------
ABC   | 1
DEF   | 33
GHI   | 18
```

And column "IDX" is an index of this Data Frame, my question is:
How can I change order of indexes in this Data Frame, because for example I would like to have Data Frame like below:

```
IDX    col1
------|-------
GHI   | 18
ABC   | 1
DEF   | 33
```

So, I do not want to cahnge the order of indexes based on some key like ascending or something liek this, I need to do it based on my priva opinion, because that's just the order I wanted :)

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
>>> df.reindex(["GHI", "ABC", "DEF"])
     col1
IDX      
GHI    18
ABC     1
DEF    33
```

Alternatively, use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
>>> df.loc[["GHI", "ABC", "DEF"]]
     col1
IDX      
GHI    18
ABC     1
DEF    33
```